# Wait window running in another thead

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Main form, which is running a synchronous operation(thus freezing the form). 
Before that starts to happen I call my function showWaitWindow().

```
    private void showWaitWindow()
    {
        Wait x = new Wait();
        x.Show(this); //"this" is allowing the form to later centralize itself to the parent
    }
```

This is where it is exactly happening:

```
        if (result)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new 
            System.Threading.ThreadStart(showWaitWindow));
            t.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = z.bg_getAllPlugins(); //Heavy synchronous call

        //This should be closing the form, which is not happening.
        for (int index = Application.OpenForms.Count; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms[index].Name == "Wait")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("found");
                Application.OpenForms[index].Close();
            }
        }
```

I've tried this without threading as well, which didn't work as well. Also, because it's trying to centralize to the parent, while being created in another thread, it throws an exception "tried to access in different thread that it was created in" rephrasing.

How do I approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `BackgroundWorker` -- available in the WinForms toolbox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //perform lengthy operation in here.
    }


}
```

Comment: I want the Main form to freeze. And using a background worker to show the Wait window is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Using the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event to close the wait form is certainly an answer.

Comment: It will not freeze the main thread, which is important to happen!

Comment: Why would you want the main thread to freeze?  Or do you just want everything disabled?

Comment: It's NEVER the correct approach to intentionally have the main thread freeze.  The user will see a "Not Responding", and will want to use task manager to close the application (for example).

Comment: The correct way to handle it, in my opinion at least, is to disable all the controls on the main thread UI so the user can't take any actions during the lengthy operation.

Comment: This is a synchronous operation. Can we just forget about the asynchronous approach and can I get a clear response on how to do it? And anyway, why doesn't that code work although it should? Despite it being in another thread everything freezes anyway before the Wait window is shown, and doesn't further close.

Comment: It depends on where in the event message loop you're calling your show and your wait message.